# excluding phpmyadmin in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, phpmyadmin

Hi I have been searching and searching for how to get this to work and cannot figure out what is wrong.  I have tried many of the solutions that have been posted and still no luck.

I would appreciate any help.

My url is being redirected to a subdirectory.  However I can not prevent phpmyadmin from not getting redirected.  Below is what I have come up with my htaccess file.  What am I missing.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redesign [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /redesign%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/phpmyadmin
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: yes this is the full htaccess rules i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test this, but maybe you can try this:

**UPDATE:** changed RewriteCond

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/redesign [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/phpmyadmin)($|/)
RewriteRule ^ /redesign%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/phpmyadmin
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

You can have more than one RewriteConditions before the RewriteRule

Comment: Instead of `^.*$ -`, just put `^ -`

Comment: I tried both suggestions and I keep getting www.domain.com/redesign/phpmyadmin instead of www.domain.com/phpmyadmin

Comment: @hozdaman, nice to hear, what´s different? - the condition `($|/)` now also considers `phpmyadmin` without a trailing slash.